# Passing newline character as variable to insertText in GAS

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, newline, google-docs

I am using an apps script Sidebar to insert text, where I enter need to append some text at the beginning, then after typing again append.

The appended text will be determined by the text box in the sidebar.

I pass the values as formObject

```
function sendform(){
    var f = document.forms[0].elements;
    var data = {        "mytext": f[0].value }
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ready).withFailureHandler(onFailure).processForm(data);
}
```

Here is the apps script code.

```
    function processForm(fO)
    {
        var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
        body.editAsText().insertText(0, "\n\nsometext"); 
// this will perfectly insert the newlinenewlinesometext to the document

        body.editAsText().insertText(0, fO.mytext); 
// this will insert \n\nsometext which is wrong 
    }
```

I tried using encodeURIComponent decodeURIComponent, but still its the same problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to first check the rules given in [Structure of a document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document) wherein you will find tree showing which text elements can be inserted and which elements can only be manipulated in place.

As mentioned, the Document Service in Apps Script can only insert certain types of elements. If you find in tree that you're trying to insert an allowable element, see [Class Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) to know the methods you can use on how to insert text such as [`insertText(offset, text)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#inserttextoffset-text).

Here's the sample code in inserting text:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

 // Use editAsText to obtain a single text element containing
 // all the characters in the document.
 var text = body.editAsText();

 // Insert text at the beginning of the document.
 text.insertText(0, 'Inserted text.\n');

 // Insert text at the end of the document.
 text.appendText('\nAppended text.');

 // Make the first half of the document blue.
 text.setForegroundColor(0, text.getText().length / 2, '#00FFFF');
```